# Create UITable with different cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a UITableView that looks like the image below, but not quite sure how to set it up. Should I create multiple custom cell, should I use sections? Or what do you guys think? Appreciate any help.

Image designed in photoshop (the blue once are buttons):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your design can be accomplished as follows:

- Create a new section for each part of the image where you placed the text "Some text here"
- For the text "Lasted updated: ...", you could use a section footer (part of UITableViewDelegate protocol)
- For the 1st and 3rd section, you could use a standard UITableViewCell with a detaillable
- For the 2nd section, you could use a UITableViewCell with a colored background

Comment: Ok, I understand! What will the `cellForItemAt` look like in this case?

Comment: It would be a distinction between which section you are in. You can check this in indexpath.section. And then you would create different functions for each case that return a uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- Create sections dependent on the number you need in your case 3 sections and dependent on section number show the cell

2- Create two custom cells `.xib` and each one has its own design and at each time you are doing `cellForItemAt` check on the cell index for the row and show the cell you need.